# Percentile interval Lemma - proof

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

Let $\theta$ be a parameter and $\hat{\theta}$ the plug-in estimate, I need a proof of the following lemma, as given in [1], p. 173, in the form of a reference or of a direct argument:

> **Percentile interval lemma**. Suppose the strictly increasing transformation $\hat{\phi}=m(\phi)$ perfectly normalizes the distribution of $\hat{\theta}$:
> $\hat{\phi}\sim\mathcal{N}(\phi,c^2)$
> for some standard deviation $c$.
> Then the percentile interval based on $\hat{\theta}$ equals: $(m^{-1}(\hat{\phi}-z^{(1-\alpha)}c),\, m^{-1}(\hat{\phi}-z^{(\alpha)}c))$.

**Reference**

[1] Efron, B. and Tibshirani, R.J. (1994) *An Introduction to the Bootstrap* (1st ed.) p. 173, Chapman and Hall/CRC

Comment: It's not true as stated.  The transformation $\hat\phi$ must be strictly increasing.  (I'm confident the authors explicitly assumed that.)

Comment: You're right, I didn't specify that. However, even if $\hat{\phi}$ is strictly increasing, I need to prove this lemma.

Comment: The proof is now complete, because $\hat\phi$ establishes a one-to-one correspondence among the intervals.  If you want to be really explicit about it, invoke the definition of "percentile interval:" the demonstration is still one short line.